# Assistance designing a WPF control template

Tags: wpf, wpf-controls, controltemplate

I am trying to design a template to be used with Bing Maps. I have started with the base template and torn a few bits out and added a few more bits, but I am making a bit of a mess of it!

What I am trying to acheive is a pushpin that has what appears to be a tooltip coming out of each side into which I can insert more information (though these are not actually tooltips; they are displayed permanantly based upon a binding property). Something like...

[image: What I have so far]

As you can see, I am not much of an artist and have not really gotten very far!

Can somebody help? What I would like is for the orange bars on each side of the pin to be able to contain text based upon a binding (and the bars should grow if required); whilst also being able to hide one or both bars depending on a binding (IsLeftTextVisible/IsRightTextVisible for example, the names do not matter I can change those later) or even if the bound field contains no text.

I would also really like for the orange bars to be a bit nicer; but if somebody can help me get to the point where I can display the text I (hopefully) should be able to take it from there.

Here is the code to produce what I have...

```
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
  xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
  xmlns:m="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Maps.MapControl.WPF;assembly=Microsoft.Maps.MapControl.WPF">

  <ControlTemplate x:Key="PushpinTemplate" 
    TargetType="{x:Type m:Pushpin}">

    <Grid Grid.Name="LayoutRoot"
      FrameworkElement.Height="{TemplateBinding FrameworkElement.Height}"
      FrameworkElement.Width="{TemplateBinding FrameworkElement.Width}">

      <Canvas FrameworkElement.Height="35"
        FrameworkElement.HorizontalAlignment="Left"
        FrameworkElement.VerticalAlignment="Top"
        FrameworkElement.Width="34">

        <Path x:Name="CollectionTextPath"
          Fill="{TemplateBinding Background}"
          Data="M 0,20 H100 V-20 H-0"
          Canvas.Left="20"
          Stretch="Fill"
          Width="100"
          Height="18.905"
          Canvas.Top="3.19"
          RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5" >

          <Path.RenderTransform>
            <TransformGroup>
              <ScaleTransform ScaleX="1"/>
              <SkewTransform/>
              <RotateTransform/>
              <TranslateTransform/>
            </TransformGroup>
          </Path.RenderTransform>

        </Path>

        <Path x:Name="DeliveryTextPath"
          Fill="{TemplateBinding Background}"
          Data="M 0,20 H100 V-20 H-0"
          Canvas.Left="-81"
          Stretch="Fill"
          Width="100"
          Height="18.905"
          Canvas.Top="4.19"
          RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5" >

          <Path.RenderTransform>
            <TransformGroup>
              <ScaleTransform ScaleX="-1"/>
              <SkewTransform/>
              <RotateTransform/>
              <TranslateTransform/>
            </TransformGroup>
          </Path.RenderTransform>

        </Path>

        <Path x:Name="Path_0"
          Stretch="Fill"
          StrokeLineJoin="Round"
          Stroke="#FF333333"
          Fill="#FFFFFFFF"
          Data="F1M13.25,0.50001502C20.2917,0.50001502 26,6.2083602 26,13.25 26,17.817347 23.598524,21.823648 19.989363,24.075348 18.67861,25.105957 17.863953,27.531982 17.863953,27.531982L13.21736,39.595642 8.6221838,27.528591C8.6221838,27.528591 7.8198605,25.084908 6.6245556,24.145586 2.952121,21.907652 0.5,17.865215 0.5,13.25 0.5,6.2083602 6.2083402,0.50001502 13.25,0.50001502z"
          UseLayoutRounding="False"
          Height="39.694"
          Width="26"
          Canvas.Left="8.282"
          Canvas.Top="0.001" />

        <Ellipse Height="21"
          Width="21"
          Fill="{TemplateBinding Background}"
          Canvas.Top="2.434"
          HorizontalAlignment="Center"
          VerticalAlignment="Center"
          Canvas.Left="10.806"
          Stroke="{x:Null}" />

        <Ellipse Height="18.905"
          Width="18.905"
          Canvas.Top="3.19"
          Canvas.Left="11.911"
          Stroke="{x:Null}">

          <Ellipse.Fill>
            <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0.5,1"
              StartPoint="0.5,0">
              <GradientStop Color="#00FFFFFF"
                Offset="0.438" />
              <GradientStop Color="#6EFFFFFF"
                Offset="0.987" />
            </LinearGradientBrush>
          </Ellipse.Fill>

        </Ellipse>

        <UIElement.RenderTransform>
          <TransformGroup>
            <TranslateTransform TranslateTransform.X="-4" />
          </TransformGroup>
        </UIElement.RenderTransform>

      </Canvas>

      <Grid FrameworkElement.HorizontalAlignment="Center"
        FrameworkElement.VerticalAlignment="Top"
        FrameworkElement.Margin="0,2,0,0"
        FrameworkElement.Height="22"
        FrameworkElement.Width="21">

        <ContentPresenter ContentPresenter.Content="{TemplateBinding ContentControl.Content}"
          FrameworkElement.HorizontalAlignment="Center"
          FrameworkElement.VerticalAlignment="Center" />

      </Grid>

    </Grid>

  </ControlTemplate>

  <Style x:Key="{x:Type m:Pushpin}"
    TargetType="{x:Type m:Pushpin}">
    <Setter Property="Template"
      Value="{StaticResource PushpinTemplate}" />
  </Style>

</ResourceDictionary>
```

As you might gather, the canvas, grids and ellipses (the bits that look nice) are from the original template. I have then added the two Paths but I am now at a loss as to how to put text inside them (I could probably bind the text without problem if I had somewhere to put it).

I know this is a bit of an ask; but is there somebody who is a bit graphical and could move me forward a bit please. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have extended the layout sufficiently.